# Using our design

Tags: css, styles

We have an agency website and found a website using our style sheets. They are linking to our domain via a HTTP to the style sheet.

Is there a way I can prevent this? I did change the name which has crashed their website however I'm looking for an actual solution.

Comment: No, there's no way you can prevent that. Your CSS needs to be publicly available so that your own users receive it.

Comment: Can I encrypt it or something?

Comment: We are using cloudflare so I can block IP address how do I block requests?

Comment: No, you can't encrypt it, that makes no sense; again, *how would your own users get it?*

Comment: They have literally copied the website design I managed to rename the stylesheet

Comment: not ideal, but you could inline all the css, minified.

Comment: @popshuvit if anything, that makes it *easier* to steal the design.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, why? theyd need to go grab new css every time something updated, vs linking to a file. css will always be public. I think jorgeRamirez has the best answer

Comment: @popshuvit because now there's only the HTML to grab. If anything it's *more* robust for the other party, because now they don't have to worry about breaking changes (e.g. renaming the file, the OP's current workaround) and they can choose when to "update" to the latest version.

Comment: Long story short, you're looking in the wrong place. You have a *legal* problem (breach of your intellectual property rights, assuming you haven't made the site available under an appropriate license), any *technical* fix is only going to be a band-aid at best.

Comment: @jonrsharpe alright lets agree to disagree. because at the end of the day, even if he blocks hotlinking with .htaccess or similarly ip blocking, they can ALWAYS come and grab the css from the live site, as long as its public facing. *shrug

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can prevent someone "hotlinking" to your resorces thru your .htaccess file. Usually the requests to static files, such as css and js, come from your own web-server in order to render the webpage. You can block hotlinking adding the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)YOURWEBSITE.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|xml|php|png|css)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Those requests don't *"come from your own web-server"*, they're being made by the client, but the referer **may** tell you what page told the browser to go get it. This will potentially also block legitimate clients, though.

Comment: No legitimate visitor will enter in their browsers the direct link to a css file. All legitimate visitors will visit a page on your site (www.example.com/page). Each page have specific static resources (css, js, etc..) that will be needed to render that page. Those resources are called by the web-server not by the visitor.

Comment: In order: not necessarily (accessing the stylesheet directly doesn't always mean intent to steal it); not necessarily (same again); yes, probably (not all pages will have static resources); and false (they are requested by the visitor's browser based on the links in the HTML). Also none of that relates to whether or not the referer is going to be set.